# Haskell Nested List Generators

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

This is a problem I've been working through on List comprehension. I know that it should be solved with recursion, but I am not sure exactly how the Haskell syntax works for the recursive case.

Here's the problem:

> Given a list of strings, output all possible combinations of those strings and 3 variables [C,U,I]. For example,
>
> ```
> list ["vC", "vU", "vI"] ==
>                  [[("vC",C),("vU",C),("vI",C)],[("vC",I),("vU",C),("vI",C)],[("vC",U),("vU",C),("vI",C)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",I),("vI",C)],[("vC",I),("vU",I),("vI",C)],[("vC",U),("vU",I),("vI",C)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",U),("vI",C)],[("vC",I),("vU",U),("vI",C)],[("vC",U),("vU",U),("vI",C)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",C),("vI",I)],[("vC",I),("vU",C),("vI",I)],[("vC",U),("vU",C),("vI",I)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",I),("vI",I)],[("vC",I),("vU",I),("vI",I)],[("vC",U),("vU",I),("vI",I)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",U),("vI",I)],[("vC",I),("vU",U),("vI",I)],[("vC",U),("vU",U),("vI",I)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",C),("vI",U)],[("vC",I),("vU",C),("vI",U)],[("vC",U),("vU",C),("vI",U)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",I),("vI",U)],[("vC",I),("vU",I),("vI",U)],[("vC",U),("vU",I),("vI",U)]
>                  ,[("vC",C),("vU",U),("vI",U)],[("vC",I),("vU",U),("vI",U)],[("vC",U),("vU",U),("vI",U)]]
> ```

Edit: So this is what I have tried so far.

```
list :: [String] -> [Dict]
list [] = [[]]
list xs = [[(x,y)] | y<-[C,U,I], x <- xs]
```

However, when I run a test case with three variables, it only outputs:

```
[[("vC",C)],[("vU",C)],[("vI",C)],[("vC",U)],[("vU",U)],[("vI",U)],[("vC",I)],[("vU",I)],[("vI",I)]]
```

Comment: What's the question? What did you attempt? Why didn't it work?

Comment: could you show us what you have tried, this seems like homework/exercise! Please show as much effort as you would expect someone answering the question putting into writing the answer. A good start would be reading the [info-page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) => section **Free Haskell Programming Books**

Comment: Edited the original post to add what I have tried so far and why it has failed. Thanks for the resource.

Comment: try to tweak this a bit: `let list [] = [[]]; list (x:xs) = [(x,c) : ys | c <-???, ys <- ??? ]` ... hint: recursion is a good idea / the order might be wrong ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, let's try to get you there step by step

Maybe you've seen the comment already but here it is with the most important step but in:

```
list []     = [[]]
list (x:xs) = [(x,c) : ys | c <- ???, ys <- list xs ]
```

notice the two cases corresponding to the two list-constructors - that's typical and you missed the second one.

Now you only have to:

- fill in the `???` it should be easy
- figure out how to fix the order (IMO it will help you understand) so that it will be exactly what your example did

---

I guess you got it - just in case the answer is:

```
list []     = [[]]
list (x:xs) = [(x,c) : ys | ys <- list xs, c <- [C,I,U] ]
```

Comment: I did work out the solution and have marked your answer as such. Thanks Carsten.